# Go time parse returning different values

Tags: parsing, time, go

I'm facing an issue where Go time parse is returning different values for two times in the same timezone.

```
func timeParse() {
    layout := "Mon, 2 Jan 2006 03:04:05 -0700 (MST)"

    value1 := "Mon, 18 Jan 2016 01:48:52 -0800 (PST)"
    value2 :=  "Tue, 19 Jan 2016 17:49:33 -0800 (PST)"

    t1, _ := time.Parse(layout, value1)
    fmt.Println(t1)

    t2, _ := time.Parse(layout, value2)
    fmt.Println(t2)
}
```

Output:

```
2016-01-18 01:48:52 -0800 PST
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Notice that the second one didn't parse properly.

Comment: `t2, _ := time.Parse()`. The "error" is with you omitting the returned `error` (the 2nd return value is an `error`). Never omit errors. Would you have printed it, you would have seen: `hour out of range`

Answer (score 1):

Found my mistake. The layout expects a 24 hour times.
Fixed with:

```
layout := "Mon, 2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700 (MST)"
```